# Android uptime in hour

Tags: android, adb, android-shell

I connect all our android devices through adb with WiFi. I am trying to get the uptime in hour. what i got now is in seconds.

```
adb connect 172.16.100.2
adb shell cat /proc/uptime > "C:\TimeLog.txt"
(or just adb shell uptime)
adb disconnect
```

The result is

```
258521.25 1019421.93
(or uptime: 2 days, 23:59:00, idle time: 11 days.....)
```

All I need is uptime in hour, I dont need 2nd part of time...

I also tried

```
adb shell awk '{print int($1/3600)":"int(($1%3600)/60)":"int($1%60)}' /proc/uptime
```

But `/system/bin/sh: aws: not found`

What else i can use with adb or shell on Android for getting uptime?

Also what command should i use to setup date/time on Android?

Comment: Is this question actually related to programming?

Comment: I think so, it is kind of  Android shell script.... If it is not, i can remove the post...

Comment: Stack Overflow is a programmers Q&A site in the sense that questions should generally relate to software that someone is developing but is having trouble with errors / crashes etc. Your question is about running an Android SDK tool from a Windows command prompt to query system info on devices. It might be better suited to http://android.stackexchange.com

Comment: if you are ok with not having leading zeroes for single digit values - `U=$(cat /proc/uptime);U=${U%%.*};H=$((U/3600));M=$((U%3600));M=$((M/60));S=$((U%60));echo $H:$M:$S`

Comment: Thanks , I just use `adb shell uptime`, that's it. no more headache....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that awk is not part of the default android installation.
If you run linux you can use:

> adb shell cat /proc/uptime | awk ...

Comment: I am running adb on windows...I could output everything first then filter from there but I wondering if there is any Android command that i can do it in one shot.

Comment: I think you are out of luck here since by default android uses shell by default. You could try this as a starter but it does not work with floating points: ` set \`cat /proc/uptime\` ; echo $(($1/3600))`